# Cannot construct a Request with a Request whose mode is 'navigate' and a non-empty RequestInit

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Consider this sample `index.html` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>test page</title>
<script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>test page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this Service Worker, designed to load from the cache, then fallback to the network if necessary.

```
cacheFirst = (request) => {
    var mycache;
    return caches.open('mycache')
        .then(cache => {
            mycache = cache;
            cache.match(request);
        })
        .then(match => match || fetch(request, {credentials: 'include'}))
        .then(response => {
            mycache.put(request, response.clone());
            return response;
        })
}

addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(cacheFirst(event.request)));
```

This fails badly on Chrome 62. Refreshing the HTML fails to load in the browser at all, with a "This site can't be reached" error; I have to shift refresh to get out of this broken state. In the console, it says:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': Cannot construct a Request with a Request whose mode is 'navigate' and a non-empty RequestInit.

"construct a Request"?! I'm not constructing a request. I'm using the event's request, unmodified. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your service worker is properly installed and registered?

Comment: It must be registered or it wouldn't be blowing up the page on refresh! Also, it shows up in the Dev Tools Applications tab as running/registered.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on further research, it turns out that I *am* constructing a Request when I `fetch(request, {credentials: 'include'})`!

Whenever you pass an options object to `fetch`, that object is the `RequestInit`, and it creates a new `Request` object when you do that. And, uh, apparently you can't ask `fetch()` to create a new `Request` in `navigate` mode and a non-empty `RequestInit` for some reason.

In my case, the event's navigation `Request` already allowed credentials, so the fix is to convert `fetch(request, {credentials: 'include'})` into `fetch(request)`.

I was fooled into thinking I needed `{credentials: 'include'}` due to [this Google documentation article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#the_defaults_of_fetch).

> When you use fetch, by default, requests won't contain credentials such as cookies. If you want credentials, instead call:
>
> ```
> fetch(url, {
>   credentials: 'include'
> })
> ```

That's only true if you pass fetch a URL, as they do in the code sample. If you have a `Request` object on hand, as we normally do in a Service Worker, the `Request` knows whether it wants to use credentials or not, so `fetch(request)` will use credentials normally.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

```
var networkDataReceived = false;
// fetch fresh data
var networkUpdate = fetch('/data.json').then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  networkDataReceived = true;
  updatePage(data);
});

// fetch cached data
caches.match('mycache').then(function(response) {
  if (!response) throw Error("No data");
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  // don't overwrite newer network data
  if (!networkDataReceived) {
    updatePage(data);
  }
}).catch(function() {
  // we didn't get cached data, the network is our last hope:
  return networkUpdate;
}).catch(showErrorMessage).then(console.log('error');
```

Best example of what you are trying to do, though you have to update your code accordingly. The web example is taken from under Cache then network.

```
for the service worker:
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('mycache').then(function(cache) {
      return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
        return response;
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

I came across this problem when trying to override `fetch` for all kinds of different assets. `navigate` mode was set for the initial `Request` that gets the `index.html` (or other `html`) file; and I wanted the same caching rules applied to it as I wanted to several other static assets.

Here are the two things I wanted to be able to accomplish:

1. When fetching static assets, I want to sometimes be able to override the `url`, meaning I want something like: `fetch(new Request(newUrl))`
2. At the same time, I want them to be fetched just as the sender intended; meaning I want to set second argument of `fetch` (i.e. the `RequestInit` object mentioned in the error message) to the `originalRequest` itself, like so: `fetch(new Request(newUrl), originalRequest)`

However the second part is not possible for requests in `navigate` mode (i.e. the initial `html` file); at the same time it is not needed, as explained by others, since it will already keep it's cookies, credentials etc.

### Solution

Here is my work-around: a versatile `fetch` that...

1. can override the URL
2. can override `RequestInit` config object
3. works with both, `navigate` as well as any other requests

```js
function fetchOverride(originalRequest, newUrl) {
  const fetchArgs = [new Request(newUrl)];
  if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
    // customize the request only if NOT in navigate mode
    //    (since in "navigate" that is not allowed)
    fetchArgs.push(request);
  }

  return fetch(...fetchArgs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was contructing a request from a serialized form in a service worker (to handle failed POSTs). In the original request it had the `mode` attribute set, which is readonly, so before one reconstructs the request, delete the `mode` attribute:

```js
delete serializedRequest["mode"];
request = new Request(serializedRequest.url, serializedRequest);
```